# How to calculate the time complexity of complex programs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm, time-complexity

I have written the following code to segregate my csv file which is stored in a dataframe and storing them in a path. I want to know the time complexity but the concept is really difficult to me to understand. Can anyone please help me in getting the time complexity of the following code

```
S = []
features_S = data.S.unique()
for f_S in features_S:
    data_S = data.loc[data.S == f_S]
    S.append(data_S)

F = []
for S in S:
    if S.empty:
        pass
    else:
        features_F = S_Name.F.unique()
        for f_F in features_F:
            data_F = S.loc[S.F == f_F]
            F.append(data_F)

D = []
for F in F:
    if F.empty:
        pass
    else:
        features_D = F.D.unique()
        for f_D in features_D:
            data_D = F.loc[F.D == f_D]
            D.append(data_D)            

M = []
for D in D:
    if D.empty:
        pass
    else:
        features_M = D.unique()
        for f_M in features_M:
            data_M = D.loc[D.M == f_M]
            M.append(data_M)
   
Y = []
for M in M:
    if M.empty:
        pass
    else:
        features_Y = M.Y.unique()
        for f_Y in features_Y:
            data_Y = M.loc[M.Y == f_Y]
            Y.append(data_Y)

Mo = []
for Y in Y:
    if Y.empty:
        pass
    else:
        features_Mo = Y.M.unique()
        for f_Mo in features_Mo:
            data_Mo = Y.loc[Y.Mo == f_Mo]
            Mo.append(data_Mo)

Da = []
for Mo in Mo:
    if Mo.empty:
        pass
    else:
        features_D = Mo.Da.unique()
        for f_Da in features_Da:
            data_Da = Mo.loc[Mo.Da == f_Da]
            Da.append(data_Da) 
 

for Da in Da:
    if Da.empty:
        pass
    else:
        PATH = f'C:/Users/Desktop/'
        if not os.path.exists(PATH):
            os.makedirs(PATH)
        Dates.to_csv(os.path.join(PATH,'Split.csv'),index=False)
```

I know whats the time complexity of a for loop O(n^2) , if else O(n^2) loop but when it comes to long codes, I don't understand how to calculate the complexity. Can anyone please explain me from the above code on how to calculate time complexity for codes like these

Comment: From the question it's not very clear where you're lost. You'll probably have better luck reading through some materials on time complexity to get a better understanding of it. From there, if you're confused, you should [edit] the question to say **specifically** what is confusing to you. You might also [edit] the question to include what you *think* the time complexity of this program is, why you think that, and why you think it's incorrect.

Comment: @Kraigolas I know the concept of time complexity but when it comes to actual codes, I am not understanding how to calculate. So if I get an explanation through the code mentioned above, it will be really helpful

Comment: Pandas is a hard library to calculate computational complexity for. For example, `data.loc[...]` can have a computational complexity of O(1) or O(N) depending on whether you're using an index or a boolean filter. For the specific problem you're facing, I will tell you that iterating over a groupby will be much faster than what you're doing. Example: `for key, subset_df in df.groupby('key'):`